# Contar el número de ceros en las filas de una matriz

Tags: r

Tengo una matriz con una estructura similar a la siguiente:

```
set.seed(2018)
x <- runif(100, 0, 100)
x <- ifelse(x < 10, 0, x)
x <- matrix(x, ncol = 10)

      [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9]    [,10]
[1,] 33.61535 39.56160 26.01008 14.13679 89.68605 40.51177 40.96630 31.21410 35.96321 84.56792
[2,] 46.37233 66.45386 56.83604 86.25990 77.29716 20.99813 35.05497 22.80563 73.90651 15.47084
[3,]  0.00000 98.21123 15.14983  0.00000 59.87828 14.48769 88.07371 92.08071  0.00000 23.52744
[4,] 19.74336 67.82154  0.00000 49.02048 59.92466 76.34911 11.42617  0.00000 39.86607 99.32754
[5,] 47.43142 80.60278 76.19166 50.61801 60.18720 66.25414 39.50146 14.11284 19.21857 21.80552
[6,] 30.10486 63.41799 53.59285 76.20344  0.00000 96.65480  0.00000 48.53343 90.90295 76.07305
[7,] 60.67589 27.07365 32.78809  0.00000 96.29126 39.32122 70.12992 61.50076 85.41415 26.82328
[8,] 13.00121 55.29041 92.43560  0.00000  0.00000 60.43476 64.57943 27.59843  0.00000 31.82381
[9,] 95.86547 73.79557 59.83117 58.10059 11.12882 26.37507  0.00000 41.81360 44.09190 94.57756
[10,] 54.68495 82.84004  0.00000 17.51324 77.42727 48.94682 54.09952  0.00000 30.78889 95.17026
```

Querría contar cuantos veces aparece el `0` en cada fila. 
Intenté usando `apply (x, 1, ...)`, pero no sé que función iría en los puntos suspensivos. Es decir, que función me serviría para contar cuantos ceros hay en cada fila.

> Nota: reproduzco una pregunta que está en espera y que creo que, reformada y con un ejemplo reproducible, valdría la pena responder porque remite a un problema general.

Answer (score 1):

## Respuesta corta

```
apply(x, 1, function (x) {sum(x == 0)})
```

## Explicación

`apply(x, 1, FUN)` se encarga de presentarle cada fila de la matriz `x` como un vector a `FUN`, que es una función.

Como no existe una función base que haga lo que queremos y no es posible usar el operador binario `==` sin indicar explícitamente cuáles son los datos a comparar, es necesario envolver el código en una función.

En este caso se aprovecha una buena característica de R, las funciones anónimas. No es necesario definirla fuera de la llamada y darle un nombre.

Esa función primero evalúa la igualdad de `x`, es decir, de cada fila de la matriz, con `0`, y regresa `TRUE` cada vez que lo encuentra y `FALSE` cuando no. Lo hace manera de vectorizada, es decir, por defecto hace la comparación en todo el vector `x`.

Por las reglas de coerción cuando pasamos un vector lógico a numérico `TRUE` se convierte en `1` y `FALSE` en `0`, así que sumando ese vector obtenemos el número de veces que aparece `0`.

## Alternativa más simple:

De manera más simple se puede usar:

```
rowSums(x == 0)
```

Con eso evitamos tener que escribir la función `apply` y generar la función anónima. (Aporte de @Patricio Moracho)

Comment: Ya lo agregué, muchas gracias! Siempre me olvido de las `row*` y me complico innecesariamente. De todos modos la opción con `apply` era la de la pregunta original.